# Hermite function expansion

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Let $f$ be a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$ with compact support and unique  maximum.  Form the functions 
$$
F_{n,k}(x)=f^n\left(x-\frac{k}{2^n}\right), k \in Z, n>0
$$

I am wondering if one can expand a Hermite function  in terms of $F_{n,k}$, i.e. something like $\sum_{k,n}c_kF_{n,k} $

Note: $
h_n(x)=(-1)^n\gamma_ne^{x^2/2} \frac{d^n}{dx^n}e^{-x^2},
$
where $\gamma_n=\pi^{-1/4}2^{-n/2}(n!)^{-1/2}$, is a Hermite function.

Thank you.

Comment: Is this homework, as some of your previous questions on MSE have been? If not, why are you looking to prove this particular result?

Comment: No, it is not a homework. In fact, my previous questions wasn't either.there was just an ideas to prove in different way some homework questions plus personal interes. The reason for my current question- I would like to study the properties of the $F_{n,k}(x)$ (if $F_{n,k}$ can form Riesz basis, Bessel system, so on). 

Comment: In what sense do you want your sum to converge?

Comment: I would like to get $L_p$ convergense. At least for $p=2$.